# in remix -> "Storage" -> what is the meaning of this top level key?

Tags: remix, contract-debugging

[image]

what is the meaning of this key?

it's not a memory address of value - this is `thisobject.key`

---

contract code (but it doesn't matter)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.5.12;

struct Xx { int256 x; }


contract Storage {
    mapping(uint256 => bool) public mappingName;
    Xx yy;
    bool mybool;
    
    constructor () {
        mybool = true;
        mybool = false;
        mappingName[1] = true;
        mappingName[4] = true;

        mappingName[3] = false;
        yy = Xx(0x01);
    }
    
    /**
     * @dev Store value in variable
     */
    function store() public returns (bool) {
        bytes32 asdf;
        assembly {
            asdf := sload(0x3f9553dc324cd1fd24b54243720c42e18e5c20165bc5e523e42b440a8654abd1)
            asdf := sload(0xada5013122d395ba3c54772283fb069b10426056ef8ca54750cb9bb552a59e7d)
            asdf := sload(0x8c5463c4917005f6f56c5b404257d4579d1c38c101ead4559bdf4510fcfa0ebd)
            asdf := sload(0x52d75039926638d3c558b2bdefb945d5be8dae29dedd1c313212a4d472d9fde5)
        }
       mappingName[1] = false;
       delete mappingName[4];

       return mappingName[1];
        
    }
}
```

---

## EDIT

in code it is called `innerkey`

https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/blob/6e896f3676a01fbb332adf6cf1873008640a49b8/libs/remix-ui/debugger-ui/src/lib/vm-debugger/dropdown-panel.tsx#L210

which is a key of `calldata` object

not this https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/blob/6e896f3676a01fbb332adf6cf1873008640a49b8/libs/remix-ui/debugger-ui/src/types/index.ts#L21

but this https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/blob/6e896f3676a01fbb332adf6cf1873008640a49b8/libs/remix-ui/debugger-ui/src/reducers/calldata.ts#L7

Comment: Can you include the contract as text?

Comment: @Ismael added, tnx